# dateparser returns wrong date when AM/PM is misspelled

Tags: python, dateparser

Is there any logic to the results below?  How can they be avoided?

```
dateparser.parse('6/16/21 11:00 ma')
```

Returns 8/7/21 2:14 PM.  This is wrong.

```
dateparser.parse('6/16/21 11:00 eb')
```

Returns 6/21/16 11:00 PM.  This is wrong, and we should prefer that the eb is uninterpretable and dateparser.parse returns None.

```
dateparser.parse('6/16/21 11:00 so')
```

Returns 6/21/16 11:00 AM.  Again, this is wrong, and we should prefer dateparser.parse to return None.

Comment: Before calling dateparser, check the string yourself to see if it ends in AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `settings=` parameter of [`dateparser.parse` function](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dateparser.parse).

These settings can be made out of multiple [different options](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html). I think `STRICT_PARSING` and `REQUIRE_PARTS` options are what you need